# How can I add comma to existing data

Tags: mysql

I have data with 6 characters like 123456 in a mysql database. I want to change the **existing data** like 123**,**456 . Is there any mysql query can do this. Because i want to change over 3000 records.

Comment: yes there are. What have you tried ? What is the data type of that column ?

Comment: data type is varchar. currently i'm adding it manually.

Comment: Is this data view in another user interface other than mysql? If so why not do the formatting when displaying data if possible.

Comment: Do not update your data. Just format it on output.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it will [FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_format) your numbers ***regardless*** of the number of digits:

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET yourfield = FORMAT(yourfield,0)
```

Comment: thanks. its working. is it working on characters also. anyway I have only numbers for that field.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET yourfield = LEFT(yourfield,3) + ',' + RIGHT(yourfield,3)
```

it will do what you asked for. Note it won't help if your field is not 6 characters long

Answer (score 0):

```
update mytable set
mycolumn = replace(mycolumn, ',', '')
```